# Map values of a nested object, and keep the generic type information

Tags: typescript

I would like to map all object values of the first obj, and keep the generic type for the Wrapped object.

I have tried this with a mapped type, but it fails in two aspects:

1. I am not able to express a nested Object in the MapToWrappedType
2. Cannot figure out how to express the type, so that the mapped type is not `Wrapper<ValueObject<...>>` but `Wrapper<...>`

From:

```js
{
 a: ValueObject<number>,
 b: ValueObject<number>,
 c: {
   d: ValueObject<string>,
   e: ValueObject<number>
 }
}
```

To:

```js
{
 a: Wrapper<number>,
 b: Wrapper<number>,
 c: {
   d: Wrapper<string>,
   e: Wrapper<number>
 }
}
```

```js
class ValueObject<T> {
  public value: T;
  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Wrapper<T> {
  public value: T;
  constructor(vo: ValueObject<T>) {
    this.value = vo.value;
  }
}

const obj = {
  a: new ValueObject<number>(1),
  b: new ValueObject<number>(2),
  c: {
    d: new ValueObject<string>("3"),
    e: new ValueObject<number>(4)
  }
} as const;

// 2 Problems:
// - how to express a nested object?
// - how to change the type to Wrapper<...> instead of Wrapper<Valueobject<...>>?
type MapToWrapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Wrapper<T[K]> 
}

function toWrappedObj<T>(obj: T): MapToWrapped<T> {
  const result: any = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    const item = obj[key];
    if (item instanceof ValueObject) {
      result[key] = new Wrapper<any>(item.value);
    } else {
      result[key] = toWrappedObj(item);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const wrappedValuesObj = toWrappedObj(obj);
const x = wrappedValuesObj.a // should be Wrapper<number>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-feather-4u0e21?file=/src/index.ts:0-1405)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8LlN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, thank you. So it is a mapped-type with a conditional-type + an infer.
Was not able to get this together myself :)
Also, thank you very much for editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

We will need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [infer keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to get rid of the `ValueObject` and replace it with `Wrapper`.

Example of `infer` from docs:

```
type Flatten<Type> = Type extends Array<infer Item> ? Item : Type;

type Result = Flatten<Array<number>> // number
```

So this example retrieves the type of the array item; we can use the same approach, but with `ValueObject`.

```
Type extends ValueObject<infer Item> ? Item : Type;
```

Then we can wrap the `Item` in `Wrapper` to get the expected result.

For the deeper levels, we will recursively call our mapper type if the mapped property is not `ValueObject`, assuming that there can't be nested `ValueObject`. Also, to make the result type more readable we will use `Prettify` utility type:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer Result
  ? {
      [K in keyof Result]: Result[K];
    }
  : never;
```

```
type MapToWrapped<T> = Prettify<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ValueObject<infer Value>
    ? Wrapper<Value>
    : MapToWrapped<T[K]>;
}>;

function toWrappedObj<T>(obj: T): MapToWrapped<T> {...}
```

Usage:

```
const obj = {
  a: new ValueObject<number>(1),
  b: new ValueObject<number>(2),
  c: {
    d: new ValueObject<string>('3'),
    e: new ValueObject<number>(4),
  },
} as const;


// const wrappedValuesObj: {
//   readonly a: Wrapper<number>;
//   readonly b: Wrapper<number>;
//   readonly c: {
//       readonly d: Wrapper<string>;
//       readonly e: Wrapper<number>;
//   };
// }
const wrappedValuesObj = toWrappedObj(obj);
const x = wrappedValuesObj.a; // Wrapper<number>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqYgK4FMDyAjAVs4AXAPACoB80A3gLABQ00ADouiAJbDQBuCKAXNIQNzVawAPYA7CLgBOiPCKkAKTkmS9CASnJDa0XAAtmEAHTKU0ALwcuyQTWgBfao6rVQkGAHUpYOnWRSiUko7BiZWKxU1W2FxSRk5RXYRXngVDGw8QM1gnV0DY1NkCw4RE2tohydqV1jcaBEsYpzoMF4xZAB3OGt0nAIxRABbdH9iBQBGdQAabXQ2zu60rD78AeHRhQAmae1gXmbaABN5rtSUXsy45jEAczGAcgBme527WlVodtOe5cy1kakYwALK9aPYZlR7C0YKIJLhbNRcABPPzQAAKUmQuFwzAAZkjAsVCNBkAAPXDIMSHGDXXH+aAAJWQEEQIFw2gA-Fo3joANoAaWg12gAGtkEiRLjGczWbgALq8JkstkCuUVMHaebsfwIqjI1EAWR8hBEXh8fkOhMsGKxOPx+GaAqFYlF4slfAVfFVJPJlOpi3OvwItPpZ2QxG0tC5Zt8-nwYYjPN4RroJpjFqIquItns2eqVFxiDEeGY4l0pu8scO6UCCgamDU6mTxor5uQlpI3JicOgmOVuF4YDESKa9gquPk0AUsMkrpHwvr2Uj0BndWYFMGxXrvLFSLVy7xU-XyE310kQ+AyHdYYuuCXPNofdlO-FcuKX2g6bjQ6RY2PgzKFR1HVBwSRACAigOHQnxVXc30sXBWyrdIFH-YDl2cDU7ExXBECkF0YPhKoXCoAB6UiV1qaAOkrC0wwgdJ9mocjoOQMBDnEEAR1aT9aLjf5RlsFjHzYjixC46A5l4tsAgEwEhIokT2M4kc9m5YTcl7USVOgY5pNjAIrluPMyMUzTMWU8SRw+L9ZKGAETI0sdmIo5xV2ovjDno9JikQr9qywOssHQqh3NJYoaLbLzrAYrAjDAfhoBY2zVns0ZqCAA)